# Call function repeatedly without overwriting passed object

Tags: actionscript-3

I am stuck with something that I am sure should be fairly straightforward. I declare two vertical lines from the library, then pass each in turn to a function which operates on the line it has been passed. The code executes without error, but apparently is overwriting the first line when the function is called the second time, presumably because of the use of the term "myLine" in the function header. Can anyone inform me how to pass each line to the same function but have the function operate on that line only?

The code is:

```
//declare new lines from library
var myLine1:letterLine = new letterLine();
var myLine2:letterLine = new letterLine();

//call function and pass each line in turn
VerticalLine(myLine1, lineX = stage.stageWidth/2 - lineOffset, lineY, lineLength, lineThickness, lineColour, lineTweenSpeed);
VerticalLine(myLine2, lineX = stage.stageWidth/2 - lineOffset, lineY, lineLength, lineThickness, lineColour, lineTweenSpeed);

//operate on the line passed to the function
function verticalLine(myLine, lineX:int, lineY:int, lineLength:Number, lineThickness:int, lineColour, lineTweenSpeed:Number):void {
    //draw line
    myLine.height = 0;
    myLine.x = lineX;
    myLine.y = lineY;
    myLine.width = lineThickness;

    var myColour:ColorTransform = myLine.transform.colorTransform;
    myColour.color = lineColour;
    myLine.transform.colorTransform = myColour;
    addChild(myLine);

    //set mask properties for line
    var maskW:uint = lineThickness;
    var maskH:uint = lineLength;

    //set gradient properties for mask
    var gradientFillType:String = GradientType.LINEAR;
    var gradientColours:Array = [0x123456, 0x654321, 0x123456, 0x654321];
    var gradientAlphas:Array = [0.4, 1, 1, 0.4];
    var gradientRatios:Array = [0, 100, 155, 255];
    var gradientMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix;

    var maskRotation:Number = Math.PI/2;
    var maskX:int = lineX;
    var maskY:int = myLine.y - lineLength/2;;
    gradientMatrix.createGradientBox(maskW, maskH, maskRotation, maskX, maskY);
    var spreadMethod:String = SpreadMethod.PAD;

    myLine.cacheAsBitmap = true;

    //draw mask shape
    var myMask = new Shape ;
    myMask.graphics.beginGradientFill(gradientFillType, gradientColours, gradientAlphas, gradientRatios, gradientMatrix, spreadMethod);
    myMask.graphics.drawRect(maskX, maskY, maskW, maskH);
    myMask.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    addChild(myMask);

    //mask line
    myLine.mask = myMask;

    TweenLite.to(myLine, lineTweenSpeed,{height:lineLength, ease:Linear.easeIn});
}
```

Comment: Post the function body. I strongly doubt what you think is happening is what's actually going on.

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that would cause what you are saying.  Thoughts: You are passing the same values both times, so both lines will be identical (or was that just for illustration of calling it twice in the post?)

Comment: Hello Jason. No, not simply an illustration - I do need to call the function twice and have it operate on two separate myline objects. A thought of my own: does it matter if a function is called *while it currently is operating on an earlier call?* In other words, does Flash stop executing (and discard) the first call and start afresh, or does it, in a sense, create as many functions as there are calls to that function in order to execute the function calls independently. Does that make sense?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is, you are sending equal values for both lines, so they strictly overlap, and you see this as an overwriting. When you call your function, you need to provide actual values for corresponding lines. Like this:

```
verticalLine(myLine1, stage.stageWidth/2 - 100, 10, 125, 1, 0xff0000, 0.2);
verticalLine(myLine2, stage.stageWidth/2 - 2, 300, 40, 2, 0x0000ff, 0.3);
```

Also check if you have proper casing when declaring the function and when calling it.

Comment: Hello Jason. The two lines of code you quoted are not identical. They pass a different object to the function - myLine1 and myLine2 - even if the parameters for each myLine that also are passed to the function are the same.

Comment: Hello Vesper - sorry about misnaming you previously. It turns out you are correct. While a separate object is being passed to the function, the position of myLine1 is identical to that of myLine2, hence why only one myLine appears! Boy do I feel stupid. Thank you very much to all who made the effort to help me - much appreciated.